# Mongo Db : elemMatch query on multiple array

Tags: mongodb

Please find below document structure of mongo Db

```
{ _id : 0,
   name : "Employee1",
   distributionList :[ { dlname : "ALLEmployee"}, {dlname:"financeall"} ],
   csrActivity : [ {activityname : "blooddonation"}, {activityname : "tree plantation"} ]

}
```

I want list of employee belonging to financeall distribution list and opted to volunteer tree plantation CSR activity.

**Expected resultset as below**

```
{ _id : 0,
   name : "Employee1",
   distributionList :[{dlname:"financeall"} ],
   csrActivity : [  {activityname : "tree plantation"} ]
}
```

But so far able to achieve below output from query

**Query** :

```
db.employee.find(
{name : "Employee1"},
{distributionList : {$eleMatch : {dlname : "financeall"}}}
)
```

**Output** :

```
{ _id : 0,
   name : "Employee1",
   distributionList :[{dlname:"financeall"} ]
}
```

Using `$elemMatch` to get the desired output but unable to find how to use it on multiple array within same document. Also tried certain combination but unable to get desired result.

Below query tried but not getting desired output

```
db.employee.find(
   {name : "Employee1"},
   {distributionList : {$eleMatch : {dlname : "financeall"}}},
   {csrActivity: {$eleMatch : {activityname : "tree plantation"}}}
)
```

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Try `db.employee.find(     {name : "Employee1"},     {distributionList : {$elemMatch : {dlname : "financeall"}},     csrActivity: {$elemMatch : {activityname : "tree plantation"}}}     )`

Comment: Already tried this query and also updated that in my question it does not work

Comment: Please take a look at the query carefully. It's not the same.

Comment: Yeah its working thanks appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only misspelled the projection operator `$elemMatch`

The correct query is:

```
db.employee.find(
  {
    name: "Employee1"
  }, {
    distributionList: {
        $elemMatch: {
            dlname: "financeall"
        }
    },
    csrActivity: {
        $elemMatch: {
            activityname: "tree plantation"
        }
    }
  }
)
```